# Unable to create popup in liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-velocity, liferay-aui

I am trying to create a popup using aui script tag and i don't no why its not working 
please have a look at the code

```
    function popup(url){

    AUI().use('aui-dialog', function(A){
        var dialog = new A.Dialog({
            title: 'Book Details',
            centered: true,
            modal: true,
            width: 500,
            height: 400
            }).plug(A.Plugin.IO,{uri: url}).render();

        }); 

}
```

Comment: are you getting any javascript error? what is the value you are passing as url?

Comment: no i am not getting any javascript error

Comment: i am passing the value as follows

    String popup = "javascript:popup('"+ viewBookURL.toString()+"');";

<liferay-ui:icon image="view" message="View Details" 
  url="<%= popup %>"/>

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into following links it may help you..

http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2013/11/working-with-liferay-alloy-ui-dialogs.html

http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2013/12/open-liferay-portlet-in-aui-dialogpopup.html